# How to use CloudWatch or Stackdriver to verify cron job ran?

Tags: amazon-ec2, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, amazon-cloudwatch, google-stackdriver

One particular use case applying to this question is that we have some resources in AWS EC2 and Google Cloud Compute with a cron job to do a nightly disk snapshot.

Is there a way to use Stackdriver to monitor the snapshot is invoked and send an alert if it doesn't?

Basically this would operate like a heartbeat, but it's only sent every 24 hours.

I think one method is to use something like "metric absence" but I don't think CloudWatch nor Stackdriver can do something like a window greater than 24 hours.

Other use cases would be any other cron job we want to monitor that are application specific, like import jobs or batch jobs.

I know there's other services that can handle this like Cronitor or OpsGenie's Heartbeats but I'm looking for a method within the same environment without additional costs.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no pre-configured metric in Stackdriver to check for snapshots.

The workaround is the one you mentioned. Every snapshot that you create on GCP generates two entries in the [logging console](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs_viewer_v2). 
You can create a Stackdriver [log based metric](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs_based_metrics) and then use it in an [Alerting Policy](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/) to notify you when [it is absent](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/#metric-absence).

Similarly, for non-GCP resources or applications, you could still [write records](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/logging/write) in Stackdriver logging, create the metric and then set the alerting over it.

The absent metric will let you set a timeframe of up to 25 hours.